# Facebook graph query different results in browser and script

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I run the following query https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Oinoscent&type=place&center=37.973880,23.732035&distance=100&access_token=$AUTHTOKEN in my browser I get the following result back

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "category": "Local business",
         "category_list": [
            {
               "id": "192661127431931",
               "name": "Wine Bar"
            }
         ],
         "location": {
            "street": "45-47 Voulis street",
            "city": "Athens",
            "state": "",
            "country": "Greece",
            "zip": "10558",
            "latitude": 37.974037344191,
            "longitude": 23.732089657161
         },
         "name": "Oinoscent",
         "id": "198585923485643"
      },
<-- cut here -->
```

as you can see the name is Oinoscent as we expect and the id is 198585923485643.

If I run the same query inside a php script I get this back

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Local business
                    [category_list] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2500
                                    [name] => Local Business
                                )

                        )

                    [location] => Array
                        (
                            [street] => 
                            [city] => Athens
                            [state] => 
                            [country] => Greece
                            [zip] => 
                            [latitude] => 37.9739041863
                            [longitude] => 23.7320465521
                        )

                    [name] => Oinoscent-Wine Bar
                    [id] => 262001553922414
                )
```

Different Name and different ID though it is exactly the same query. Does  anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Are you using the same access token in both cases? (Btw., Facebook has merged the second page with the first one, so in the end they are both the same. If that merge happened recently, then that might explain different results.)

Comment: yes, the same access token is used in both cases, and yes i saw that its a merge but for some reason in the php script i keep getting the "old" page and in the browser the new

Comment: Hi Leonidas, I'd be interested to see the PHP code (and what version of the PHP SDK) you're using. I tried a few queries targeting different versions of the Graph API and couldn't reproduce this unfortunately. Under the covers the PHP SDK just makes Graph API calls after all.

Comment: hey david i was fetching everything with curl i did not use the sdk for this